# VBA Access 213 add new record using ADODB connector and M

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba, adodb

When I run this script everything is ok. But record insert with method 1 don't give any result:

```vb
Sub ADOMYSQL()
    Dim dbc As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim conn As String

    Set dbc = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    conn = "DSN=mysql;Server=127.0.0.1;Uid=root;Pwd=1234;DATABASE=ndb;PORT=3306;DFLT_BIGINT_BIND_STR=1"

    With dbc
        .ConnectionString = conn
        .ConnectionTimeout = 30
        .Open
    End With

    Do While dbc.State > ADODB.adStateOpen
        DoEvents
    Loop

    If dbc.State = ADODB.adStateClosed Then End
       dbc.Execute "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytbl"
       dbc.Execute "CREATE TABLE mytbl(id int not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT, data varchar(20))"

       'rs insert methode 2
       With rs
           Set .ActiveConnection = dbc
           .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
           .LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
           .Source = "SELECT * FROM mytbl"
           .Open
           .AddNew
           !Data = "method 1"
           .Update
           .Close
       End With

       'rs insert methode 1
       With rs
           .Open "SELECT * FROM mytbl", conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
           .AddNew
           !Data = "method 2"
           .Update
           .Close
       End With

End Sub
```

here the result in the MYSQL db :

[image: MySQL Result]

Comment: VBA is missing an `End If` which should have raised an error. Also, *conn* is only a string here and you need an active connection object in `rs.Open`. Again, this should have raised an error.

Comment: using select query with Both method give same result

Comment: I made no mention of SQL query. What is you last comment answering?